# Magento 2 : getting index table error after save product from backend after version upgrade from 2.4.3 to 2.4.5

Tags: product, catalog, backend

SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM `catalog_product_index_price_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`)

Answer (score 3):

We had the same error logged when running the **indexer_update_all_views** cron task. Manually reindexing everything fixed the issue.

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Edit:
This issue still occurred, someone else kindly made a fix for it https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/36370

Composer patch for magento/module-catalog below:

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/AbstractAction.php b/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/AbstractAction.php
index e69ab504880ef..219467033ecde 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/AbstractAction.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Indexer/Product/Price/AbstractAction.php
@@ -179,7 +179,8 @@ protected function _syncData(array $processIds = [])
         // for backward compatibility split data from old idx table on dimension tables
         foreach ($this->dimensionCollectionFactory->create() as $dimensions) {
             $insertSelect = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
-                ['ip_tmp' => $this->_defaultIndexerResource->getIdxTable()]
+                ['ip_tmp' => $this->_defaultIndexerResource->getIdxTable()],
+                array_keys($this->getConnection()->describeTable($this->tableMaintainer->getMainTableByDimensions($dimensions)))
             );
 
             foreach ($dimensions as $dimension) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Then run commands upgrade and others

Comment: I am getting another error while generating the whitelist json.

`Warning: Undefined array key "column" in vendor/magento/module-developer/Model/Setup/Declaration/Schema/WhitelistGenerator.php on line 197`

When I have tried to debug the reason behind the above error, then found that **catalog_category_entity_datetime** doesn't have a column key which cause the issue. 

`Array
(
    [referenceId] => CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_DATETIME_ENTITY_ID
    [disabled] => 1
)`

Comment: It looks like running the generate-whitelist command will throw an error if an extension has disabled an index or constraint via a db_schema.xml file. You can try temporarily commenting out those lines & rerunning the command.

Comment: actual fix is here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b7f562bc628ae8d664d2c1083a84ae9f7c9ae566