# New custom product type - order cancel getting error in magento 2.4.5 and greater version

Tags: price, magento2.4.5, install-script, custom-product-type, patch-data

A new product type created using following link

https://aureatelabs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-new-product-type-in-magento-2/

New product type is successfully created and Order placed for new product type.
When tried to cancel the order of a new product type getting the following error.
Order cancel working on Magento version 2.4.4 using same code

> SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136
> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT
> INTO `catalog_product_index_price` SELECT `ip_tmp`.* FROM
> `catalog_product_index_price_temp` AS `ip_tmp` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
> `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`),
> `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` =
> VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` =
> VALUES(`tier_price`)

Comment: You can follow this Link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361707/magento-2-getting-index-table-error-after-save-product-from-backend-after-vers